# Question Closed in Favor of an Answer that was Stated as Unsatisfactory

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I'm not sure just what the process was behind [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/214995/101310) being closed. Honestly, it feels as if someone was either in a hurry to just close it or wasn't looking over everything, including the comments. Also, One important comment has been deleted.

I posted the question before going to sleep. I'm looking for a way to do a popup in Blender, with Python, that is modal (in other words - stops a script until I respond to it) and a popup. Note that's 2 main points: 1) Modal, 2) Popup. I woke up and there were two comments, one by @Alexbries, with 2 links that I looked over and another by @p2or, with another link. I looked over that, as well.

I responded to the first comment about those links not providing what I had hoped they would and what I thought was a problem with what I was trying to do. Then I looked at the link @p2or provided and found it wouldn't work. I explained why: The answer in that link did not provide a true popup, but a panel in the 3D VIEW space that (at least when I ran the code in the answer) would not show up unless you had the tabs pulled out and were looking at the right tab. No popup - which is an important part of the question.

Later I come back and find the question is closed because there is an answer already provided on another question. I go there, hoping for a good answer and it's the same answer that had been given in @p2or's comment, the one I said was not a full answer. So I was thinking, "Maybe the person who closed it didn't pay attention to everything here," and looked and that comment, with the link to that answer, was gone.

I feel a bit like I'm in a whack-a-mole game. I get a comment suggesting an answer and I check on it and leave a comment why it's not a suitable answer. Then I come back, find that comment (with the link) deleted. My reasoning why that answer wouldn't work is still there, in a comment, but someone has now closed the question - for the same reason given in that now deleted comment. BUT - my explanation would still apply, which means if the person closing the question had inspected the code in that answer AND my comment, they'd have seen the reason that answer doesn't work.

I'm trying to get an answer to this, even if it is, "You can't do this with a popup." I've gone through man SE:Blender questions and answers, through Blender forums, and still can't get a clear answer on this - and the answer some people think is an answer is not.

If someone knows of an answer that works and can point it out, I'm fine with the question being marked as a duplicate, but that's not happened and I don't want to have to keep repeating that this one answer does not answer the question.

Comment: Hello and welcome. If you feel a question was incorrectly [marked as duplicate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates), or the linked posts don't adequately address the issue, please don't post the same question more than once, instead edit the question including information of what you have tried, why it failed and how the duplicates don't address your issue. Once edited the question is automatically queued up for review so it can be reopened. You can also manually flag it for reopening

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos: Done, but I'm also trying to understand why I had to deal with the same point twice - and why, with my comment on why that answer on the other question was not acceptable didn't seem to matter when it was closed. I'm trying to understand what was going on as much as anything. Even if it's someone saying, "Oops - okay, I missed that detail," that's fine. (And it's reopened - so that's good!)

Comment: As you have already seen comments on this site are more of a temporary discussion that may be deleted at any time even by the system itself. That is why you are encouraged to add additional information by editing your question rather than post comments below that may be easily missed, as was the case here.

Comment: Also flags for duplicates raised by other users remain active even after you comment or edit in your question, unless they manually retract them after the fact. Since they were not removed, as I glossed over review queues I assumed those duplicates did answer your question so I erroneously confirmed the duplicate and closed it. Other than that we are all humans and make mistakes from time to time don't make a big thing of it. If you question gets closed don't take it personally, use the site tools to get your question reopened and keep an open attitude about it, it happens all the time.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos: Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Fwiw you went about this in a kind and understanding way, welcome to the site

Comment: @AllenSimpson: Thank you. I still had to close it. Someone who suggested the links I had said (in the edit) didn't work were good. I said, "Tried, it won't work," and he insisted it would. I feel the OP has a responsibility to specify if suggestions work or don't (for future readers). It was an endless loop! I wish he had been right, but he was using links I already said didn't work. I finally told him if it worked, write a clear answer - he didn't. It was wasting so much time, I finally had to close it. I was less than kind with him because he wasn't listening and it was quite aggravating.